# How to delete a particular pattern from a line in linux using wildcard

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

how to delete a particular pattern from a line in linux using wildcard?

```
test07cel20: ((host=test07db04.com,port=1832,community=public,(host=test07db02.com,port=1832,community=public),(host=172.186.100.63,port=162,community=public,type=ASR))
```

I want to delete `(host=172.186.100.63,port=162,community=public,type=ASR)` from the above line and `172.186.100.63`, `public` will change case by case (I mean variables), so looking for some wildcard method.

Also, this pattern will exist always in the end of the line. In some cases, `type=ASR` will be `type=asr`. So if you have any idea to cover all the above scenarios for deleting the pattern `host=*,port=162,community=*,type=ASR` from a line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

expected output is

```
(host=test07db04.com,port=1832,community=public),(host=test07db02.com,port=1832,community=public)
```

Comment: Edit your post with appropriate formatting and add an expected output.

Comment: Your edit made it unclear: it it's a single line, it should be shown as a single line (as code, with four indents).

Comment: now i make it as a single line.when i was searching for the help,i was getting delete the line using wildcard but not delete the particular pattern from a line.Please help

Comment: tried myself and got the answer       echo "((host=test07db04.com,port=1832,community=public),(host=test07db02.com,port=1832,community=public),(host=172.186.100.63,port=162,community=public,type=ASR))"|sed 's/((/(/g'|sed 's/))/)/g'|sed 's~),(~) (~g'|tr " " "\n"|sed '$ d'|tr "\n" ","|sed 's/.$//'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is unnecessarily complicated. Try something like this:

```
sed 's/,(host=[^(]*,port=162,[^(]*type=[Aa][Ss][Rr])//'
```